# What is basic difference between themes and modules in drupal?

Tags: 7, theming

Is there any difference between modules and themes if so then what are the basic difference in between them? If there is no difference then what is the concept behind having separate folder for both of them?

Comment: you're asking a very broad question web development question. What exactly in the official drupal documentation at Drupal.org is not worded good enough for you to understand? What research have you done and what is your understanding of why they are separate?

Comment: Themes are for the display, modules are for functionality.

Comment: You question is about a general software architectural and design issue. The common metaphor for web development is 1. retrieving/storing data, 2. manipulating data (applying business logic) and 3. presenting data. This allows for separation of concerns, easier testing, pluggability (ie swapping different databases in and out, different business logic, and different themes etc), and ease of workflow (themers can work on look and feel and coders can work of functionality). With no separation of concerns everything will end up in a big mess all too soon.